# Get INDEX of two or more words in one string & Input it into array

Tags: c#

i wanna get some values of words in single string in c# winform, for example :

```
string paragraph = "Youre entering something that will entering you";
```

how should i do to get the `entering` words indexes and put it into an array?

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Such as using [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @chansiara you may want to read [ask] and share your research. "find all indexes of substring in string" yields plenty of search results.

Comment: i wanna get those values into array, indexOf can't get two values of index except you do the process twice, and i asking for single process bro. @UnholySheep

Comment: I am not your *"bro"*. And there's this thing called "loops".

Comment: Then put that "single process" in a method which calls `IndexOf()` in a loop and adds the result to a collection, returning that. This is shown in the duplicate and many other search results.

Comment: sorry for @CodeCaster. i don't mean to duplicate it. i just can't find any answer and really confused

Comment: okay, i got it ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through Regex.

```
var indexes = Regex.Matches(paragraph, @"\bentering\b").Cast<Match>().Select(x=> x.Index).ToList();
```